# Eager loading on polymorphic relations

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5

```
class Admin {
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Models\User', 'humanable');
    }

    public function master()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Master');
    }
}


class Master {
    public function admin()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Admin');
    }
}

class User {
    public function humanable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\Image');
    }
}

class Image {
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

Now if I dump this:

```
return \App\Models\Admin::where('id',1)->with(array('user.images','master'))->first();
```

I get the perfect result one master, one user and one image record.

But if I do this

```
return $user = \App\Models\User::where('id',1)->with(array('humanable','humanable.master'))->first();
```

I only get one Admin record, the query get * from masters doesn't even run.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, I'm sure this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly Laravel has lots of pitfall. You can try to use the `protected $with` var in Admin model instead of query builder with function.

```
class Admin {
    protected $with = ['master'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Models\User', 'humanable');
    }

    public function master() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Master');
    }
}
```

In query builder, only need to include `humanable`. Now you should see master inside the humanable object.

```
return $user = \App\Models\User::where('id',1)->with('humanable')->first();
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help. Strange that it works likes this and not within the query.

Comment: I want to give you the correct answer but the systems saying I need a reputation of 15 before being allowed. I'm new so will do in the future.